# How to make the inputbox appear?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a program that allows users to see information on songs, play an excerpt of them, and purchase selected ones.

And allow users to click the Purchase button to buy the indicated tune.

When checking out:

Users cannot checkout if they have not purchased any tunes, however they can exit the program.

Use an InputBox so that users can enter their sales tax rate. Since users are entering a value, you must perform data validation on their input.

Allow users to cancel the check out process by clicking the InputBox Cancel button.

**When the input box is displayed, the textbox should have the focus, and when an incorrect tax value is added, the incorrect value should be cleared and the textbox should have focus again.**

Use Write/Writeline to create a purchase order text file named PurchaseOrder.txt that includes the date the file was created and an itemized list of purchases, the subtotal, tax, and total.

Same question as before, but the inputbox isn't appearing. Look for **cmdCheckOut_Click** subroutine in my code and find this:

```
str1 = InputBox("Enter your tax rate as a % between and including 0 - 10:", "Tax Rate", "", -1, -1)
```

My code:

```
Public Structure musicInfo
  <VBFixedString(30)> Public title As String
  <VBFixedString(20)> Public artist As String
  <VBFixedString(20)> Public genre As String
  <VBFixedString(10)> Public duration As String
  Public year As Integer
  Public price As Double
  <VBFixedString(15)> Public songFileName As String
End Structure

Public Const NoOfTunes = 5
Public songs(NoOfTunes - 1) As musicInfo

Option Explicit On
Imports System.IO
  Public Class frmTunes
  Public index As Integer
  Public purchaseCount As Integer
  Public purchasePrice(10) As Decimal
  Public purchaseTitle(10) As String
  Dim decimal1 As Decimal
  Dim decimal3 As Decimal
  Dim decimal4 As Decimal

Private Sub frmTunes_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim i As Integer

    FileOpen(1, "music.dat", OpenMode.Random, , , Len(songs(0)))
    For i = 0 To NoOfTunes - 1
        FileGet(1, songs(i))
    Next
    FileClose(1)

    cmdPrevious.Visible = False

    DisplaySong(0)
End Sub

Sub DisplaySong(ByVal i As Int32)
    lblTitle.Text = songs(i).title
    lblArtist.Text = songs(i).artist
    lblGenre.Text = songs(i).genre
    lblDuration.Text = songs(i).duration
    lblYear.Text = Convert.ToString(songs(i).year)
    lblPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(songs(i).price)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdStop.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPurchase_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPurchase.Click
    purchaseTitle(purchaseCount) = lblTitle.Text
    purchasePrice(purchaseCount) = Convert.ToDecimal(lblPrice.Text)
    purchaseCount = (purchaseCount + 1)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPrevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPrevious.Click
    index = (index - 1)
    If (index < 4) Then
        cmdNext.Visible = True
    End If
    If (index = 0) Then
        cmdPrevious.Visible = False
    End If
    DisplaySong(index)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdNext.Click
    index = (index + 1)
    If (index = NoOfTunes - 1) Then
        cmdNext.Visible = False
    End If
    If (index > 0) Then
        cmdPrevious.Visible = True
    End If
    DisplaySong(index)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPlay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPlay.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(songs(index).songFileName)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCheckOut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCheckOut.Click
    Dim str1 As String = ""
    If (purchaseCount = 0) Then
        MsgBox("You have not ordered any items!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Order Error")
    Else
        Do While ((IsNumeric(str1) Or (Decimal.Compare(decimal3, Decimal.Zero) < 0)) Or (Decimal.Compare(decimal3, (10D)) > 0))
            str1 = InputBox("Enter your tax rate as a % between and including 0 - 10:", "Tax Rate", "", -1, -1)
            If (str1 <> "") Then

            End If
            If (IsNumeric(str1)) Then
                MsgBox("You must enter a numeric tax rate", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Tax Rate Error")
            Else
                Dim decimal3 As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(str1)
                If ((Decimal.Compare(decimal3, Decimal.Zero) < 0) Or (Decimal.Compare(decimal3, (10D)) > 0)) Then
                    MsgBox("You must enter a tax rate between and including 0% - 10%", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Tax Rate Error")
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        Dim StreamWriter As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("PurchaseOrder.txt")
        StreamWriter.WriteLine("For Purchases dated: " & DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
        StreamWriter.WriteLine()
        Dim num2 As Integer = (purchaseCount - 1)
        Dim num1 As Integer = 0
        Do While (num1 <= num2)
            StreamWriter.Write(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(Me.purchasePrice(num1), Decimal) & vbTab & "     "))
            StreamWriter.WriteLine(purchaseTitle(num1))
            Dim decimal1 As Decimal = Decimal.Add(Nothing, purchasePrice(num1))
            num1 = (num1 + 1)

        Loop
        StreamWriter.WriteLine("------")
        StreamWriter.WriteLine(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(decimal1, Decimal)) & " Subtotal")
        Dim decimal2 As Decimal = New Decimal(((Convert.ToDouble(decimal3) * 0.01) * Convert.ToDouble(decimal1)))
        StreamWriter.WriteLine(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(decimal2, Decimal)) & "  Tax")
        StreamWriter.WriteLine("------")
        Dim decimal4 As Decimal = Decimal.Add(decimal1, decimal2)
        StreamWriter.WriteLine(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(decimal4, Decimal)) & "  Total")
        MsgBox("Purchase Order has been created", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        StreamWriter.Close()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: well, did you debug the code to see if it is getting to the Do while condition where it then proceeds to show the Inputbox?

Comment: I did, but nothing showed up.

Comment: well for me, using a brand new project and with a simple line of code: dim strInput = InputBox("Hello", "Enter Input", "", -1, -1) works for me. So it is to do with the code. I don't believe you have placed a breakpoint on the inputbox line to see if it actually is hitting it...?

Answer (score 2):

So, you're problem is in this line:

```
Do While ((IsNumeric(str1) Or (Decimal.Compare(decimal3, Decimal.Zero) < 0)) Or (Decimal.Compare(decimal3, (10D)) > 0))
```

Your conditions are not being met, so the code inside the loop never runs.

Comment: Step back a bit...what are you trying to do with this line? `Do While` what?